# React Context variable is null inside callback function

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-typescript

I created a custom hook to check for MenusContext being `null` because I don't have a default context value. Next, I used it in the Menus Compound Component, which is a small dropdown menu with edit, copy, and delete actions. It opens and closes when I am opening different Menu but It doesn't close when clicking on the same Menu. I console logged `openId` variable in the `Toggle` component itself and inside the callback function where instead of showing the same value as `id` it shows `null`. From what I've seen `openId` isn't overwriting or something, it's still the latest value in React Tree when clicked on a specific menu.

[image: openId exist in React Tree]

[image: Scope issues, openId is null]

useMenusContext custom hook

```
import { createContext, useContext } from 'react';

type MenusContextTypes = {
  openId: number | null | undefined;
  close: () => void;
  open: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number | null | undefined>>;
  position: { x: number; y: number } | null;
  setPosition: React.Dispatch<
    React.SetStateAction<{ x: number; y: number } | null>
  >;
};

const MenusContext = createContext<MenusContextTypes | null>(null);

const useMenusContext = () => {
  const menusContext = useContext(MenusContext);

  if (!menusContext) {
    throw new Error(
      'useMenusContext has to be used outside of <MenusContext.Provider>'
    );
  }
  return menusContext;
};

export { useMenusContext, MenusContext };
```

Component

```
type StyledListProps = {
  position: { x: number; y: number } | null;
};

type MenusProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

type ToggleProps = {
  id: number | undefined;
};

type ListProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  id: number | undefined;
};

type ButtonProps = {
  children: string;
  icon: React.ReactElement;
  onClick?: () => void;
};

export default function Menus({ children }: MenusProps) {
  const [openId, setOpenId] = useState<number | null | undefined>(null);
  const [position, setPosition] = useState<{ x: number; y: number } | null>(
    null
  );
  const close = () => setOpenId(null);
  const open = setOpenId;

  return (
    <MenusContext.Provider
      value={{ openId, close, open, position, setPosition }}
    >
      {children}
    </MenusContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Toggle({ id }: ToggleProps) {
  const { openId, close, open, setPosition } = useMenusContext();

  console.log(openId);

  function handleClick(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {
    const rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
    setPosition({
      x: window.innerWidth - rect.width - rect.x,
      y: rect.y + rect.height + 8,
    });

    console.log(openId, id);

    openId === null || openId !== id ? open(id) : close();
  }

  return (
    <StyledToggle onClick={handleClick}>
      <HiEllipsisVertical />
    </StyledToggle>
  );
}
```